# ActionEvents in matlab without if statements once a condition is met

Tags: matlab, callback

I'm creating a matlab application without a gui, and I'm pretty new to action events and callbacks. I can only find documentation regarding action events that either use the gui, or create a listener that is called upon the program hitting an if statement. I'd like to be able to use action events dynamically, and have them be called whenever a specific condition is met. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you expand a bit more... What kind of app is it? What kind of components are you working with? What's the condition?

Comment: the `listener` can trigger on some property change, which is probably what you are after. It doesn't need an `if` condition.

Comment: @Paolo I want the program to have a counter that triggers an event whenever a certain number is reached.

Comment: @Hoki Do you have an example of this? I am unable to find any examples that use action events without the gui, and the way you defined. How are you able to have a trigger cause a listener without a triggerEvent containing if statements?

 I am stuck on having if statements in my 
`
            triggerEvent(obj)
`
function

Comment: No specific example, but the documentation has several examples: [Create event listener bound to event source](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html). Or this example make use of `listener` without a gui: [Event and Listener Concepts](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-concepts.html)